# scandir() scan by increasing number

Tags: php

I want to scan a directory and add all the file-names to an array in ascending order (numeric, no letters). What appears to be happening is `scandir()` is sorting them by highest value of the first number and not the whole number. I need to take into account missing text files, so if `9.txt` was missing, `10.txt` would take its place (no empty spot in array).

Here is the code:

```
<?php

$array=array();
$int = 1;
$holder=scandir("/postexamples/");
krsort($holder);
foreach($holder as $x)
{
    if(!is_dir($x)){
    $array[$int]=$x;
    $int++;
    }
}
echo PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL . "Final array: " , PHP_EOL;
print_r($array);

?>
```

Which outputs the array:

```
Array ( [1] => 9.txt [2] => 8.txt [3] => 7.txt [4] => 6.txt [5] => 5.txt [6] => 4.txt [7] => 3.txt [8] => 20.txt [9] => 2.txt [10] => 19.txt [11] => 18.txt [12] => 17.txt [13] => 16.txt [14] => 15.txt [15] => 14.txt [16] => 13.txt [17] => 12.txt [18] => 11.txt [19] => 10.txt [20] => 1.txt )
```

Is there a better (and preferably working) way to do this? I need it to be like `[1] => 1.txt [2] => 2.txt`

EDIT:

I need the array to appear like this:

```
Array ( [1] => 1.txt [2] => 2.txt [3] => 3.txt [4] => 4.txt [5] => 5.txt [6] => 6.txt [7] => 7.txt [8] => 8.txt [9] => 9.txt [10] => 10.txt [11] => 11.txt [12] => 12.txt [13] => 13.txt [14] => 14.txt [15] => 15.txt [16] => 16.txt [17] => 17.txt [18] => 18.txt [19] => 19.txt [20] => 20.txt )
```

And if one file (for example, `17.txt`) was missing, it would look like this:

```
Array ( [1] => 1.txt [2] => 2.txt [3] => 3.txt [4] => 4.txt [5] => 5.txt [6] => 6.txt [7] => 7.txt [8] => 8.txt [9] => 9.txt [10] => 10.txt [11] => 11.txt [12] => 12.txt [13] => 13.txt [14] => 14.txt [15] => 15.txt [16] => 16.txt [17] => 18.txt [18] => 19.txt [19] => 20.txt )
```

Comment: Why don't you just sort the array afterwords,

Comment: `krsort($holder);`? Tried that.

Comment: wrong sorting try rsort( $array ) on the results after building the array, to reset the keys do array_values( $array ).  krsort the way you are using it is same as array_reverse()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do a natural sort to get the files in the correct order (20.txt, 10.txt, 2.txt, 1.txt). The function for doing this is [natsort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php).

```
$sortPath = 'postexamples/';

$files = array();
foreach (scandir($sortPath) as $file) {

    if (is_file("$sortPath/$file")) {
        $files[] = $file;
    }
}

echo PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL . "Final array: " , PHP_EOL;
natsort($files);
$files = array_values($files);  // re-key array
print_r($files);
```

### Result

```
Final array:

Array
(
    [0] => 1.txt
    [1] => 2.txt
    [2] => 4.txt
    [3] => 10.txt
    [4] => 20.txt
)
```

Comment: I removed the array_reverse step after you updated your original question.

Comment: It appeared all scrambled after I removed the `$files = array_reverse($files);` line, so I re-added it along with an additional one and it fixed the problem! Thank you very much!

Comment: 2 array reverses? why dont you just do array_values to reset the keys.

Comment: Ok, that one works as well. I'll use that one instead. Thanks again!

Comment: Sorry about that. The array_reverse re-keys the array after the sort. You can accomplish the same thing with `$files = array_values($files)`. I have updated the example.

Answer (score 1):

Id do it like this.

```
   $files = array_diff(scandir("/postexamples/"), array('.', '..' ));
   $array = array();
   foreach($files as $file){
        if(!is_dir($file)){
            $array[]=$file;
        }
   }
   sort($array, SORT_NUMERIC);
```

You may have to use usort, if it doesn't do the numbers right.  Also if you are on php >= 5.4 you may be able to use,

```
scandir("/postexamples/", SCANDIR_SORT_ASCENDING );
```

But I haven't tried it.  Using sort with numeric flag ( don't forget it's just an array like any other )

```
$a = Array ( '9.txt', '8.txt', '7.txt', '6.txt', '10.txt', '1.txt');
echo "<pre>";
var_export($a);
echo "<br>";
sort($a, SORT_NUMERIC);
var_export($a);
```

Result

```
array (
  0 => '9.txt',
  1 => '8.txt',
  2 => '7.txt',
  3 => '6.txt',
  4 => '10.txt',
  5 => '1.txt',
)
array (
  0 => '1.txt',
  1 => '6.txt',
  2 => '7.txt',
  3 => '8.txt',
  4 => '9.txt',
  5 => '10.txt',
)
```

So essentially `sort($a, SORT_NUMERIC);`

Answer (score 0):

Try this ,i hope this will help you:

```
$ar=array();
$g=scandir("/postexamples/");
krsort($g)
foreach($g as $x)
{
    if(is_dir($x))$ar[$x]=scandir($x);
    else $ar[]=$x;
}
print_r(sort($ar));
```